# mysql2: Cannot find mysql_config at /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config after system upgrade

Tags: mysql, macos-mojave, mysql2, mysql-5.6

I upgraded mac OS Mojave from `v10.14.0` to `v10.14.2` and all the packages I installed with Homebrew. MySQL got upgraded from `v5.6.42` to `v5.6.46`. After the upgrade `mysql2` gem started to fail to compile with:

```
    current directory: /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20191218-70879-1yhhybm.rb extconf.rb
--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Cannot find mysql_config at /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config
-----
```

I looked at the contents of the `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6` folder and there is no `5.6.42` directory in it:

```
ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/

total 0
drwxr-xr-x  16 hirurg103  staff  512 Dec 18 13:50 5.6.46_2
```

I am using `mysql2` version `0.4.4`

Do you have any ideas how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by running `gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.4` with `--with-mysql-config` argument:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.4 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.46_2/bin/mysql_config
```

After this `bundle install` went without errors